# what does 'a set of vectors is linearly dependent in a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ ' mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

while I was reading the Exercises sheet of linear algebra of my friend I came across this question

$$ E = \{(x-2y,x-2y,0,x-y-z-t)\; |\;x,y,z,t\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

show that the set of vectors $V=\{(1,1,0,1),(-2,-2,0,-1),(0,0,0,1)\}$
is linearly dependent in $E$

ok this set is clearly linearly dependent in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and it also spans $E$ but the fact that I didn't quite get the question is bothering me.

if someone can shed some light on this it will be great

thanks!

Comment: If they are dependent in $\mathbb{R}^4$, then they are automatically dependent in $E$.  If it's the "in $E$" part that's troubling, the exercise is only trying to stress that the vectors are all in $E$.

Comment: I believe you could consider this a trick question. The property of a subset of a vector space to be linearly dependent or independent does not change if you restrict to a subspace which contains this subset.

Comment: It still is very confusing, but I think I can understand what was meant. Anyway, if it is "clearly dependent" then **what** exactly is your question?

Comment: @DonAntonio usually they ask you if it's linearly dependent in a vector space 

here E is a subspace of a vector space but now I think I get it's the same thing I just have to check if E is itself a vector space first

Comment: @rapidracim Of course. A vector subspace is a vector space in its own right. That it is **subspace** is only due to the fact that it is a subset of another, bigger vector space.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to write the zero-vector as an explicit nontrivial linear combination of the vectors in $V$.

Comment: this is exactly the method I used to show that it's minearly dependant in $R^4$

$2*(1,1,0,1)+(-2,-2,0,-1)-(0,0,0,1) = 0$